# UINavigationController vs viewController embed in NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was trying my hands on iOS and while building apps, one question get into mind that what is the difference between UINavigationController vs viewController embed in NavigationController.

While using UINavigationController we push and pop views.
while using viewController we present and dismiss.

SO what are the applications where one is more superior to use than the other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751457/difference-between-navigation-controller-and-viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UINavigationController` is used where you want you move back and forth in your application. Generally Navigation controller is used when you are navigating in more detailed information in each level of depth you are in your application.
[image]

`UIViewController` is generally preferred when you display polished information. in `UINavigationController` generally it is the one of the last controller you push in your controller

Answer (score 0):

I think you are really describing two sides to the same coin. There is only one way to use a UINavigationViewContorller. It is a known as a container view controller and its job is to push and pop other UIViewControllers.  A UINavigationViewController works with viewControllers, not views.

Answer (score 0):

**UINavigationController:**
If you have hierarchy of view controller then that is you have stack of view then  you need to use navigation controller. You can perfrom push and pop operations on the view controller and Navigation Controller is the rootViewController of all ViewController.so to go back to the previous one, in a ordered way. Imagine that controllers in a navigation controller will just build a sequence from left to right.

**UIViewController:**  if you are using view controller it act as presentViewController. The presentViewController offers a mechanism to display a so-called modal view controller; i.e., a view controller that will take full control of your UI by being superimposed on top of a presenting controller. I think that presentViewController is most suitable for use with just one view controller being presented at a time. So you simply will not be able to implement a "go back"/navigation like functionality.

Answer (score 0):

**UINavigationController** inherits from **UIViewController**. The strange thing about this object model is the UIViewController has a property called NavigationController. So for OO purists this is a bit baffling that a parent class knows about its children. But moaning aside this is how it’s been done in UIKit. As you’ll find with a runtime error, you can’t place a UINavigationController inside a UINavigationController

Whenever you push a controller, it can access the parent UINavigationController it may or may not belong to via the NavigationController property. The property is null if the controller is not inside a UINavigationController.